# Node distance option does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to align the centers of a string of nodes while placing them below each other.

**Here is my problem:**

I tried to set the distance between the nodes after specifying the alignment I want. The output however is far from the intended.I think it has something to do with when the different commands is compiled.

**What would be the right way to align the nodes properly and then afterwards specify the distances between them?**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node [draw] (A) at (4,5) {AAAA};
    \node [draw,below=of A.center , node distance = 10cm] (B) {B};


    \node [draw,below=of A.center , node distance = 20cm] (C) {C};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can't specify the `node distance` after `below` (it uses the default 1cm instead). Change the order or use the more appropriate `below=10cm of A.center`. That said, how do you actually want to place the nodes? 10cm/20cm between their centers or between the borders? The way you do it now is 10cm/20cm between A's center and the new nodes' border. Maybe you want to place them [`on grid`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/on:grid) (then you can drop the `.center`)?

Comment: You can also use a tikz matrix (page 710).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple nodes below the same node, you can use this syntax to specify how far below the node they should be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node [draw] (A) at (4,5) {AAAA};
    \node [draw,below=5cm of A.center] (B) {B};


    \node [draw,below=10cm of A.center] (C) {C};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could position `C` below `B` and avoid the hard coded distances:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
    
    \node [draw] (A) at (4,5) {AAAA};
    \node [draw,below=of A.center] (B) {B};
    \node [draw,below=of B.center] (C) {C};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by positioning c below B to void the hard coded distances?

Comment: @DanielDeWet I added a second example